# How to make a 2D model(moveable) like gomoji app?

Tags: ios, svg, sprite-kit, scenekit, avatar

I want to make a 2D model in iOS programatically. Like this:

[image]

This is taken from the app [Gomoji](http://www.getgomoji.com).

I googled it but not get the proper solution. 
This character is also moving so it can move hands and the legs meanwhile I want to change the colour of the hands etc.

Could it be possible with SpriteKit, SceneKit, gif, SVG or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

This is an incredible amount of work in code, with SpriteKit and actions.

You might be better off using the puppet features of After Effects to creation motion frame sequences, and then bring them into SpriteKit and string them together and jump between the sequences as necessary.

Start here, to understand the puppetry tools in AE:

https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/animating-puppet-tools.html

Once you've learnt the lingo, head on over to youtube to pick up tips on how to do 2D arms, head wobbles, etc.

There's also a face animator in the latest versions of After Effects, that might be helpful, too.

Generally speaking, this is still a lot of work. And a lot of fiddling to get it to look "just so". But doing this visually, with manual mouse controls and instant playback before exporting image sequences from AE will be lightyears faster than attempting to do this with joints and code in SpriteKit or any other game engine.

Comment: Is there any idea other than this?
Could it be possible with GameKit or image sequence, or Avatar modeling.